# javascript how to make json from string?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, parsing, header

I have string

```js
let str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0';
```

I would like to make it as like this.

```json
{
   1:2,
   3:4,
   5:6,
   7:8,
   9:0
}
```

How can I do this ?

Only using map function can not solve this.

Comment: [Step 1](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+comma+separated+string+to+array+of+numbers): [How to convert comma separated string into numeric array in javascript](/q/16396124/4642212). [Step 2](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+array+key1%2C+value1%2C+key2%2C+value2+to+object): [Chain of \[key1, value1, key2, value2, ...\] to object](/q/63513716/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [**Array.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do it

```js
let str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0';
let result = str.split(',').reduce((a,v,i,arr) => {
  if(i%2 != 0){
     a[arr.at(i-1)] = v
   }
  return a
},{})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: So fast reply.. Thanks.  Actually what I want is this . {
   '1':'2',
   '3':'4',
   '5':'6',
   '7':'8',
   '9':'0'
} 
How can I do this ? a[arr.at(i - 1).toString() ] = v is not working